# Swift Eureka SplitRow values updating

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to update values of each LabelRow in my SplitRow every time VC appears one the screen (it has to be like that). I've tried using .cellUpdate on both LabelRows but it just crashes. When I use .updateCell on just one of LabelRows, it updates value of that row just fine. Is there a way to update both of them at the same time? I tried to use .updateCell on SplitRow but then I can't update values (they are read-only?).
The failing code part:

```
            <<< SplitRow<LabelRow, LabelRow>() {
            $0.rowLeftPercentage = 0.5
            $0.rowLeft = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Expected"
                $0.tag = "temp_expected"
            } //tried callbacks here

            $0.rowRight = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Last"
                $0.tag = "temp_last"
            } //tried callbacks
        } //also tried there but cant update values
```

EDIT: here's what I've tried

```
            <<< SplitRow<LabelRow, LabelRow>() {
            $0.rowLeftPercentage = 0.5
            $0.rowLeft = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Expected"
                $0.tag = "temp_expected"
            }.cellUpdate {
                $1.value = "value1" //here would go value from other object, doesn't work either
            }
            $0.rowRight = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Last"
                $0.tag = "temp_last"
            } .cellUpdate {
                $1.value = "value2" // same as above
            }
        }
```

And other one

```
            <<< SplitRow<LabelRow, LabelRow>() {
            $0.rowLeftPercentage = 0.5
            $0.rowLeft = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Expected"
                $0.tag = "temp_expected"
            }
            $0.rowRight = LabelRow() {
                $0.title = "Last"
                $0.tag = "temp_last"
            }
        }.cellUpdate {
            $1.value?.left = "value1" //does nothing
            $1.value?.right = "value2" //does nothing
        }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Yup, I've edited main post

Comment: I don't think you should be setting a row's value in `cellUpdate`... Can you set it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashes because of a stack overflow. The setter of `$1.value` calls `cell.update()`, which calls `cellUpdate`, which forms an infinite loop :(

I've found this *dirty trick* that kind of works:

Wrap the `row.value = ...` line in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call:

```
SplitRow<LabelRow, LabelRow>() {
    $0.rowLeftPercentage = 0.5
    $0.rowLeft = LabelRow() {
        $0.title = "A"
        $0.tag = "temp_expected"
    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            row.value = ...
        }
    }
    $0.rowRight = LabelRow() {
        $0.title = "B"
        $0.tag = "temp_last"
    } .cellUpdate { cell, row in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            row.value = ...
        }
    }
}
```

In reality though, you should find another place to set your row's value. It sounds like the value changes over time and you want to always show the latest value. Try using a Reactive approach using [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift). You'd subscribe to an `Observable<String>`, and set each value you receive to the row's value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to just change values in a different place ;) btw .cellUpdate description on Eureka github is very misleading!

Comment: Did so ;) I'm really glad you helped me